# onClick event not working in LinearLayout if all components are shown and there's space left in Android API 27

Tags: android, android-layout, events, android-linearlayout

I'm testing my app with Android API 27 with the biggest screen size available for emulated devices.

If some condition happens my app should be able to react if the user presses in a void space (one with no UI element) or a passive element (like a TextView).

From APIs 18 to 26 if there were space left after the last element in the LinearLayout were displayed if the user pressed there it reacted accordingly, but in API 27 it just ignores it, but works if something like a TextView is tapped.

I've tried to solve this by creating an invisible TextView that would fill all that free space, either by putting it at last element or putting it on the middle, but it doesn't work, I've done it this 2 ways.

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true">
        [moreelements]
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewextra"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

and on the other hand:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true">
        [moreelements]
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewextra"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        [moreelements]
    </LinearLayout>



 </ScrollView>
```

But in API 27 it doesn't even fill the screen, and still keeps on no reacting.

How could this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially wanting the empty space to be clickable, and perform some action?

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/someId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Will fill the empty space, and then just set an OnClickListener to it.